# Who to install PCNTL Extension on Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, whm, pcntl

I am using php version 5.5.3 and want to install PCNTL,
can you help me?
It's VPS and I have root and WHM.
I tried:

- Get your current php version (check phpinfo())
- Get the sources for that version here: http://www.php.net/releases/
- Extract this file; you will got folder name like php5-x.x.x
- Run following lines in terminal:

  ```
  cd php5-x.x.x/ext/pcntl
  phpize
  ./configure
  make
  cp modules/pcntl.so /usr/lib/php/modules/
  echo "extension=pcntl.so" > /etc/php.d/pcntl.ini
  restart apache
  ```

  Note: if your /usr/lib/php/modules/ or /etc/php.d/ is not same
  as this, you could try 'locate php/modules' or 'locate php.d'

Answer (score 0):

To install pcntl on cpanel server you need to rebuild apache and php  on your server

First create /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5 file on your server and add following code.

```
–enable-pcntl
```

Then rebuild apache and php using **/scripts/easyapache**

Once the rebuild completes, Check using php -m

Comment: i tried this but after easy apache 3 rebuilding it was showing error.
then i installed Easy apache 4 and php v5.6
it's working now
Thanks